# Job Recommendations on profile page should not be static

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, activity-tab, stack-overflow-jobs

I notice that the "Activity Page" (https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) job posts component always shows the same positions. 
This makes it pretty relevant since I've already reviewed/applied to these 4 positions.

I think it would be helpful to shuffle the displayed ads or perhaps add a scroll to allow viewing more relevant postings.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

What i would suggest here is that the jobs that appear may have a link button for **Not Interested** or **Skip/View Next** which would tell that user is not interested in this particular job and that would cause that particular job post to disappear and in place of that a new job posting can appear which can possibly be a suitable or user might be interested in that one and can apply.

I also agree on [@Amna's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352546/1875256) that the post on which user has already applied shouldn't appear there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there are not many jobs opportunities, for that we see just few positions.
also another guess, I think Job Recommendations is in the test version, we have to wait maybe some weeks to see more than 4 positions

Comment: When I go into the Jobs page I see hundreds or even thousands of them with paging. So I don't think this is the cause. My guess is developers took top(4) :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if there aren't many job opportunities posted at stack overflow but still I agree with your recommendation that at least the ones you have applied, must not appear there anymore.